# Android 2 google maps maps in one application

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout

In my application I have 3 google maps maps on diffrent activitys ofcourse. If I go to one location in one map in one view. And then start the other activity. The map will be located on the location where the other map left of.

Is there any way I can prevent this? (hope you understand the problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting [the documentation](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapActivity.html):

> Only one MapActivity is supported per process. Multiple MapActivities running simultaneously are likely to interfere in unexpected and undesired ways.

You will need to rewrite your application to only have one `MapActivity` and change the contents (overlays, center/zoom, etc.) as needed.

Comment: I need to make one MapActivity? And re-use this one? Do you have an example because I don't completly understand it. I think I will have a problem. Because I have one map who will need buttons and one who doesn't. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @TimonDevos: "Because I have one map who will need buttons and one who doesn't" -- then hide and show the buttons.